# why does subtraction from unsigned integer constant print out this output?

Tags: c

```
{
   printf("%lld\n", -9223372036854775807ull - 1);

}
```

*expected* output : **9223372036854775808**

*actual* output : **-9223372036854775808**

i know about wrapping around of unsigned integer but why *subtracting* **1** from an unsigned long long which wraps up to **9223372036854775809** did not give the result **9223372036854775808**.

Can you give me a step by step **explanation** what happens here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The range of a signed 64 bit width value in twos complement is from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807 including. The number -9223372036854775808 is just in range.

Comment: thanks for the answer....what about the first part of question ??

Comment: I'm sorry, which is the first part?

Comment: If you want an unsigned value printed, use `%llu`.

Comment: i was expecting a positive value of 9223372036854775808 as the -9223372036854775807ull wraps up to 9223372036854775809 and subtracting 1 from it yields to 9223372036854775808

Comment: Your 'wraps up' claim is wrong — it doesn't.

Comment: so the suffix doesnt matter?I want to know how does it work...what is the process that is occuring here?

Answer (score 2):

> Also the result goes beyond the range of a signed long long.

The actual output suggest that it does not.

Most architectures use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent negative numbers in binary.

The range of a signed 64 bit width value in twos complement is from `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807` including. The number `-9223372036854775808` is just in range.

The `-9223372036854775807` is equal to `0x8000000000000001`. Minus 1 that's `0x8000000000000000`, which is equal to `-9223372036854775808`.

If your code would overflow (underflow) an integer of type `long long`, then the behavior of your program would be [undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior according to the C standard. In C you can't have expectations for any behavior from a code that does underflow an signed integer (or you should be aware of your compiler that allows such behavior).

Comment: why does this statement `printf("%lld",-9223372036854775808)` prints **-1** though it is in range

Comment: That's a funny one. `-9223372036854775808` is interpreted as `-` with `9223372036854775808`. Then number `9223372036854775808` is too big to fit into `long long` so `unsinged long long` is used. Then `-` is applied, and `unsigned long long` is converted to a `long long` value. Which result's in conversion. You could also read [cppreference integer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) the examples below.

Comment: "... and `unsigned long long` is converted to a `long long` value" --> There is no proper conversion.

Answer (score 1):

"Fundamentally, what the computer is presented with is a pattern of bits."  If you choose to interpret the leftmost bit as a "sign bit," then you might get a "negative" number.  Whereas, if you don't, you will get a (much larger) "positive" number.  The computer really doesn't care.

"The pattern of bits does not change."  If you choose to interpret them as a two's complement signed value, that's fine.  Likewise if `MSB=1` doesn't matter to you, that's fine too.  You can format your printed output either way.

Comment: doesnt the expression -9223372036854775807ull wraps up to 9223372036854775809 and so subtracting 1 from it yields to 9223372036854775808 ?

Answer (score 1):

`-9223372036854775807ull - 1` becomes `9223372036854775808ull` due to wrap-around of the (supoosed) 64-bit `unsigned long long`.  This is well defined.  Nothing to do with 2's complement.

```
// like
(ULLONG_MAX + 1) - 9223372036854775807 - 1 --> 9223372036854775808
```

Printing with non-matching specifiers is usual *undefined behavior* (UB), except for corresponding integers of the same positive range.  C17dr §6.5.2.2 6

Output is UB as `9223372036854775808ull` is outside the positive range for `long long` and `"%lld"`.

It appears to have wrapped, but that is UB.

If you want to print the `unsigned long long` result of `-9223372036854775807ull - 1`, use:

```
//  not  lld
printf("%llu\n", -9223372036854775807ull - 1);
```